# Understanding LVM2 behavior in case of disk failure?

Tags: filesystems, lvm, raid

I have a LVM2 group using the following command for a 5x4TB set up:

```
pvcreate /dev/sd{b,c,d,e,f}
vgcreate vg0 /dev/sd{b,c,d,e,f}
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n lvol1 vg0
```

Now that I created this monster, I have some question about it: in the default configuration which happens to be linear, what happens if `/dev/sdb` fails ?

- Should I say good bye to the whole `/dev/sdb` data or LVM is placing the files on the whole device rather than trying to fill in the first bytes ?
- How can I tell which file is on which device ? If I am to lost a disk, I'd like to know where the data is lost in order to be able to restore it if possible.

**Note:**

- I followed [Gentoo handbook for the LVM creation](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM#PV_.28Physical_Volume.29).
- I understand perfectly that RAIDx (and LVM to my understanding) does not provide a backup; they can only at most add resilience against disk failure. I have some experience with (software) RAID5 and disk failure: luckily enough, only one at a time failed. However, I have no experience with LVM and that is why I'm asking those questions.

Answer (score 7):

`lvdisplay --maps` will tell you where the physical extents corresponding to a particular LV or a specific range of it are located. `pvdisplay --maps` presents the same information from a PV-centric viewpoint.

For example, if `pvdisplay --maps` indicates that a failing PV covers, say, logical extents 1000...4000 of a particular LV, and the extent size of that VG is 4 MiB, then you'll know that if the PV were to completely fail, your LV would have a big inaccessible "hole" in it, starting at a point 4000 MiB from the start of the LV and continuing until the point 16000 MiB from the start of that LV.

Usually, in situations like this, it will be easiest to restore the whole LV: that way you can be sure that all the files are in a consistent state. For example, if file A contains references to things in file B, you might want to restore both from backups even if only one was on the damaged area.

But if you must (i.e. you found out that you have no usable backups and are now in deep trouble), you can use `lvchange` or `vgchange` with the `--activationmode partial` to activate a LV even if it has parts missing, so that you can mount it to recover whatever is remaining. This should be done **only** for data recovery purposes.

Since in your case `/dev/sdb` would be the first PV in the volume group, it would also hold the first part of the LV - which is where a lot of critical filesystem metadata of that LV would probably end up, so `fsck` would spew a lot of errors at you. As frostschutz said, `photorec` could very well find any unfragmented files from the remaining parts of the LV. But relying on that is bad strategy.

You'll need to think about backups, and the amount of time a full restore would take. If restoring the entire LV after a disk failure would take too much time, you'll need to add redundancy to the system to avoid that. Typically that means getting more disks and putting your data on some sort of RAID array.

But even if you set up a RAID array, don't forget about backups. RAID may make disk failures easy to deal with, but it is of no help at all in the event of a user/sysadmin "oops". **RAID is not a backup.**

Answer (score 2):

> what happens if /dev/sdb fails?

Your lvol1 will no longer work. Losing one drive means losing 5 drives worth of data. The volume will have a huge chunk of data missing (entire disk gone) and most likely, whichever filesystem you are using on top of that won't like it one bit.

You should not expect `fsck` to recover anything. It could happen, but `fsck` is not a data recovery tool, it's mostly used to fix minor inconsistencies only, not magically work around hundreds of gigabytes worth of data gone missing. Sometimes `fsck` is perfectly happy to provide you with a consistent (yet strangely empty) filesystem.

If you do use `fsck`, or anything else for that matter, do it with a snapshot or overlay so you can undo any changes made. (Data recovery mandates working in read-only, or copy-on-write mode.)

Since LVM is linear (by default, anyhow), `photorec` and other tools will still be able to find (unfragmented, unencrypted) data on the other drives.

While LVM will happily span across many drives, it may be better to create several smaller volumes. Volumes that were not located on the missing drive will survive. Smaller filesystems also avoids a problem with `fsck`, which tends to be very resource hungry and take a very long time, depending on filesystem size.

Using unpartitioned drives comes with the risk of inadvertently creating a partition table anyway - overwriting other metadata in the process. You should always use a partition table.

In any case, if you do not want to lose your data, make backups.

If you don't want to restore backups after every single drive failure, also use RAID.

Comment: As I understand, if I'm afraid of disk failure, should I rather use 5 * ext4 partitions or RAID5 ? But isn't RAID5 (or 6) _risky_ for 5x4TB especially while rebuilding the Array ?
_You should always use a partition table_: are you speaking about the fact I used /dev/sdb rather than /dev/sdb1 ? I only followed this doc: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM#PV_.28Physical_Volume.29

Comment: Yes, partition it (with GPT for >2TB drives) and then use sdb1. RAID is not risky "especially while rebuilding the Array". A rebuild is a completely linear and very boring process. It IS risky if you never test your hard drives, because then the rebuild will also be your first ever hard drive test in years and likely run into previously undetected errors. And thus people blame RAID rebuilds for their lack of disk monitoring. You still need backups with RAID in any case.

Comment: I think you've talked me out of using lvm, for anything other than recycle bin type data anyway. I should stick to overlayfs if I want to have a single view of the data.

Answer (score 1):

LVM does not place any files. LVM creates a large logical device whose data is distributed over several physical devices.

That is like having a 1GiB partition, formatting it, creating data in the filesystem and then overwriting the range 250MiB to 500MiB with zeroes.

If there were less than 250MiB of data in the filesystem then there is a chance that `fsck` may restore most or all of it. You can easily give that a try.